# Express/Node JS - Should ypu always check if document exist in database?

Tags: node.js, express

I got into a habit to have extensive error checking so I always check whether document of user exist before editing or doing something within the controller, but I wonder is this really necessary? For example, within social network app, when user sends friend request, I find "Friends" model and before pushing user id in list, I check whether list exists even though I know I created it when user signed up.

Comment: Can you provide code example please

Comment: "Necessary" lies in the eye of the beholder (and the data model, and whether or not these things are ever deleted, and whether or not it matters if invalid (either "physically" or semantically) data exists in the system, ... etc.)